# Cummulative left overs using SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using an older version of sybase which does not have keywords like lead.

I want to find cumulative left over.

Let me try to explain this with an example.

StartQuantity = 500

```
Category   Time        Quantity        LeftOver
cat1      10:01:01.000     100           400 
cat1      10:01.01.001     50            350
cat1      10:01:01.002      0            350
cat1      10:01.01.003    100            250
cat1      10:01:03.001    100            150
```

Similar rows are available in cat2 and the number of rows per category is variable.

Please note that in above I have arranged the rows in ascending order of time.

Comment: what about 500 - `sum(quantity) over (partition by category order by time)` that generates a running `sum()` in a standard compliant database.

Comment: can you please write me a detailed code. I am not very good at SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Sybase supports this, but in PostgreSQL, Oracle and others you can do

```
select category,
       time,
       quantity, 
       500 - sum(quantity) over (partition by category order by time) as leftover
from the_unknown_table;
order by category, time
```

Comment: I get the following error by using the code above: Syntax error - Order By key must be a numeric data in RANGE Window Frame. Can anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: @user1949158 So what datatime is `TIME`?

Comment: TIME in my database is of type 'timestamp'. So, an example of time as in my database is: '2012-03-23 11:27:04.870000'. Thanks

Comment: @user1949158: well apparently Sybase does not support this then, because it does work in Oracle or PostgreSQL.

Comment: I just started a new thread for converting timestamp to unixtime. This will help me use the order keyword. Do you mind replying to that one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Category, SUM(500-(Quantity))
FROM table_name
group by Category

OR

SELECT Category,(count(1)*500)-sum(Qunatity)
FROM table_name
group by Category